# Apache Lucene - search by concrete date

Tags: lucene

I want to find some data of a application which allows using Apache Lucene syntax for search queries. I search data by date and want to find data from concrete date - concrete day. How can I do that?

Queries:

```
date: [2010-10-4 TO 2010-10-4]
```

or

```
date: 2010-10-4
```

does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** there is no "standard" for date query syntax in Lucene. You need to find out the format(s) your app supports.

**Long answer:** For the last couple years or so, Lucene keeps the numeric data specially encoded. Most likely, the date in the index is kept in the timestamp format. This means the query parser needs to take in the query, chew it and spit out the timestamp. Querying against a raw timestamp is not very practical - at least for humans - and your query parser likely has some pre-defined format it is able to understand.

For example, Solr has a [pre-defined set of supported date/time formats](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api-4_0_0-BETA/org/apache/solr/schema/DateField.html) and is able to parse those into timestamps.

Don't forget Lucene is just a library and each application (including Solr and the one you are using) is meant to use it the way they like.

Comment: Thank you for this info. And sorry for my too general question about Apache Lucene.

Comment: No problem! I hope this will be still useful for someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
For searching by one conrete day, query:

```
date: [2010-10-4T00:00:00 TO 2010-10-4T23:59:59]
```

is correct

Comment: It is only correct for your app. Other applications can (and do) implement their own date formats.

Comment: It's also only correct if you don't care about the last second of the day... Many other folks might prefer to use an exclusive upper bound to avoid gaps.

Answer (score 0):

I put the date range without the hyphens and It worked for me.

```
date: [20210901 TO 20211101 ]
```

See the doc [Range Searches](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Range%20Searches)

Comment: Unrelated: i agree to that comment that you just got on your date-related answer that was deleted with the corresponding question: please educate yourself about current day Java date/time libraries (see https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro) ... simply do not recommend other newbie programmers to use that outdated and error prone Calendar stuff.